# SystemJS Typescript reference paths on System.import with an application added to the site

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I have a url like this: http://www.foo.com/bar/ (Bar is my application name in IIS to access that application under the Default Website).

In MVC and importing files and such as style sheets in my head tag, I can typically use "~/Content/foo.css".

In SystemJS I am trying to import my main.js file which is located in "Scripts/typescript/main.js" but i need it to be in reference of my application name (bar above).

Here's what I have right now:

```html
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            './Scripts/typescript': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });

    System.import('./Scripts/typescript/main.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

The problem is, this looks at the root, so it's trying to access www.foo.com/Scripts/typescript/main.js when I really need it to access www.foo.com/bar/Scripts/typescript.main.js.

I don't want to hard code the app name into my URL because it won't work where that app name is different or doesnt exist.

Can someone help me so that it knows how to access the correct path?

Comment: There is a confusion about the application name (you use foo and bar as app name).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set following property [System.baseURL](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/overview.md#baseurl).

You can do it in the object passed to the `config` method.

```
System.config({
    baseURL: '/foo',
    packages: {
        './Scripts/typescript': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But what if the app name changes or goes away? Then I have to change my code every time.

Comment: @Bohms27 Yes, unless you can get the app name dynamically and inject it in that file somehow.

Comment: I did this and it fixed the issue with it not being able to find my "Scripts/typescript/main.js" file, but now it's having issues with node_modules and such. For instance it's looking for "foo.com/bar/angular2/core.js" but cant find it because it's really in the "foo.com/bar/node_modules/angular2/core.js". Do I need to have nodejs installed on my web server?

Comment: @Bohms27 Please accept the answer if it fixed the issue. Regarding the other issue, you can have a look at System.map property or even jspm :)
No, you don't need to have nodejs installed in your web server.